# bind selected option value to ng-model instead of selected text

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating new user by getting user's input. User can select their state from the dropdown. I want to save the state id instead of state name  when the user select the state. How to assign state id to newSiteObj.st model.

modalStates = [0: {id: 53, name: "A"} , 1: {zid: 56, zn: "B"}]

```
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" ng-model="newObj.name" class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
<div>
    <label>State</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="state" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search State" ng-model="newSiteObj.st">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <option ng-repeat="state in modalStates" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to already assign state id to newSiteObj.st

Comment: @ethvlad my newSiteObj.st returns only  the state name not state id

Comment: Check out the output of `newSiteObj.st` on your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/zga4aO7IUyQLMtnI4DhH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You cant bind a select to a property, try

```
ng-model="newSiteObjectState"
```